# iMacros if a tag is a empty value, set it to a default value

Tags: imacros

I am new to Imacros and simply trying to complete a textbox with a default value if it is empty. If it is not empty, then the code will ignore the fill.
Can anybody help me how to make this?
Basically what I need is:
If the textbox named PHONE is empty, then fill it with 555-2828
If it has a phone already, then ignore the fill.